# Simple HelloWorld app on cloudrun (or knative) seems too slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, knative-serving, knative

I deployed a sample HelloWorld app on `Google Cloud Run`, which is basically `k-native`, and every call to the API takes 1.4 seconds at best, in an end-to-end manner. Is it supposed to be so?

The sample app is at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy

I deployed the very same app on my localhost as a docker container and it takes about 22ms, end-to-end.

The same app on my `GKE` cluster takes about 150 ms, end-to-end.

```py
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    target = os.environ.get('TARGET', 'World')
    return 'Hello {}!\n'.format(target)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

I am a little experience in FaaS and I expect API calls would get faster as I invoked them in a row. (as in cold start vs. warm start)

But no matter how many times I execute the command it doesn't go below 1.4 seconds.

I think the network distance isn't the dominant factor here. The round-trip time via ping to the API endpoint is only 50ms away, more or less

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is it potentially an unintended bug? Is it a technical difficulty which will be resolved eventually? Or maybe nothing's wrong, it's just the SLA of `k-native`?
2. If nothing's wrong with `Google Cloud Run` and/or `k-native`, what is the dominant time-consuming factor here for my API call? I'd love to learn the mechanism.

---

Additional Details:

- Where I am located at: Seoul/Asia
- The region for my Cloud Run app: us-central1
- type of Internet connection I am testing under: Business, Wired
- app's container image size: 343.3MB
- the bucket location that Container Registry is using: gcr.io

[WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190530_FG_56bd0bf8ca35191597994ed2cf22c9e8/2/details/#waterfall_view_step1) from Seoul/Asia (warmup time):

- Content Type: text/html
- Request Start: 0.44 s
- DNS Lookup: 249 ms
- Initial Connection: 59 ms
- SSL Negotiation: 106 ms
- Time to First Byte: 961 ms
- Content Download: 2 ms

[WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190530_NB_18daf8786f41ca64e1666dd0ac98adc3/2/details/#waterfall_view_step1) from Chicago/US (warmup time):

- Content Type: text/html
- Request Start: 0.171 s
- DNS Lookup: 41 ms
- Initial Connection: 29 ms
- SSL Negotiation: 57 ms
- Time to First Byte: 61 ms
- Content Download: 3 ms

---

ANSWER by Steren, the Cloud Run product manager

> We have detected high latency when calling Cloud Run services from
>   some particular regions in the world. Sadly, Seoul seems to be one of
>   them.

Comment: Do you see any errors/crashes in the container logs?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I deployed the sample (https://github.com/knative/docs/tree/master/docs/serving/samples/hello-world/helloworld-python) to my account, and it constantly serves around 150 ms on my residential network connection (except the first call). Please contact Google Cloud support with your account/project details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update: This person has a networking problem in his area. I tested his endpoint from Seattle with no problems. Details in the comments below.]

I have worked with Cloud Run constantly for the past several months. I have deployed several production applications and dozens of test services. I am in Seattle, Cloud Run is in us-central1. I have never noticed a delay. Actually, I am impressed with how fast a container starts up.

For one of my services, I am seeing cold start time to first byte of 485ms. Next invocation 266ms, 360ms. My container is checking SSL certificates (2) on the Internet. The response time is very good.

For another service which is a PHP website, time to first byte on cold start is 312ms, then 94ms, 112ms.

What could be factors that are different for you?

1. How large is your container image? Check Container Registry for the size. My containers are under 100 MB. The larger the container the longer the cold start time.
2. Where is the bucket located that Container Registry is using? You want the bucket to be in us-central1 or at least US. This will change soon with when new Cloud Run regions are announced.
3. What type of Internet connection are you testing under? Home based or Business. Wireless or Ethernet connection? Where in the world are you testing from? Launch a temporary Compute Engine instance, repeat your tests to Cloud Run and compare. This will remove your ISP from the equation.

Increase the memory allocated to the container. Does this affect performance? Python/Flask does not require much memory, my containers are typically 128 MB and 256 MB. Container images are loaded into memory, so if you have a bloated container, you might now have enough memory left reducing performance.

What does Stackdriver logs show you? You can see container starts, requests, and container terminations.

Comment: I am located in South Korea and the region is the same as yours, us-central1.
Do you think it's the network distance problem? Here is how I timed it, just now.
`$ time curl https://helloworld-uplrvvyqza-uc.a.run.app/
Hello World!

real 0m1.434s
user 0m0.024s
sys 0m0.008s
`
Since you are in Seattle, what do you see if you run the same command as mine: `$ time curl https://helloworld-uplrvvyqza-uc.a.run.app/`?

Comment: Don't use `time`. Curl has built-in features. You want to measure time to first byte: `curl example.com -w "%{time_starttransfer}\n". However, you did not answer a single question I asked except where you are located. You must do the work to debug, we can only give you advice.

Comment: And the reason why I think it would not be an issue of network distance is as follows: `$ ping -c 3 helloworld-uplrvvyqza-uc.a.run.app
PING helloworld-uplrvvyqza-uc.a.run.app (216.239.36.53): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.239.36.53: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=36.539 ms
64 bytes from 216.239.36.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=36.611 ms
64 bytes from 216.239.36.53: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=40.553 ms

--- helloworld-uplrvvyqza-uc.a.run.app ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 36.539/37.901/40.553/1.875 ms`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am going to answer to what you asked for. I just wanted to cross out the network factor first.

Comment: Edit your question for additional information. Do not use comments. Also, I covered in detail how to debug this. Using `time`, `ping`, etc will not help you. For ping, you are measuring response time to the load balancer front-end and not your Cloud Run service.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the question. Thanks for the tips. I'll get back to you with further details :)

Comment: You have not ruled out networking being the problem. Ping is abused as an end-all solution. It is not. It is just a tool to measure round-trip times for the ICMP protocol. This has nothing to do with HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Note: I did not notice your Cloud Run service URL. I just checked from Seattle. I am seeing normal response times (similar to mine) - yours is 30ms faster. My guess is your connection to your ISP. Launch a small instance near you and test using that instance. This will remove your ISP connection.

Comment: Security Warning: Since you have published your service endpoint. Delete it and create a new service with a different name. Protect yourself.

Comment: I edited my question. I see the same result as yours when I run the cURL in the USA. It's reasonably fast. Now, do you think it is safe to say that the main reason being so slow from Seoul/Asia to my app in us-central1 is due to inter-ISP delay?

Comment: And thanks for the security warning. I am going to shut down it before it's too late.

Comment: At this point, I can only speculate. I would create an VM instance in Asia and test from there. Your problem is most likely your ISP connection.

Comment: According to all the metrics I collected and logs on Stackdriver, it is due to network distance, not the app itself. The app mostly finishes its job done within 1 ms so now I can tell the most portion of the TTFB was for the network. Hence one more question for you. The SSL negotiation did just take 106 ms when TTFB took 961 ms from Asia to us-central1. Doesn't SSL negotiation go through ISP in this case? Why do you speculate the SSL handshake takes so much less than TTFB? Does SSL negotiation take place somewhere else nearer by me even though I cURL my app in us-central1?

Comment: SSL negotiation is between the client (e.g. web browser) and the Googe Load Balancer Front-end. Once this completes, the Load Balancer proxies over HTTP to your Cloud Run service. I do not know the details on the Cloud Run Front-end meaning for normal HTTP Load Balancers; they are global. Given that Cloud Run is in beta, they might be Regional at this time (I am guessing). I would create a new question asking this as the Cloud Run team monitors this tag. I am interested in the answer.

Comment: However, when measuring you need to be specific on what you are measuring and from where. Your home Internet does not count - too many variables for home ISPs.

Comment: Thank you for all. I'll consider a new question any you suggested :)

Comment: One more thing. What did you mean by an issue for `my ISP`? Was my very ISP throttling the outbound traffic to Cloud Run one of your concerns? Or, did you mean any/some ISP(s) between my terminal and my app in Cloud Run? What possible factors by an ISP do you speculate caused such a long TTFB(961ms) for my case?

Comment: What I am saying is that your ISP, my ISP, etc. has traffic patterns that we cannot control. All of your neighbors could be watching movies, etc. When debugging a problem, try to remove the unknowns, so that you can get better information.

Answer (score 0):

(Cloud Run product manager here)

We have detected high latency when calling Cloud Run services from some particular regions in the world. Sadly, Seoul seems to be one of them.

We will explicitly capture this as a [Known issue](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues) and we are working on fixing this before General Availability. Feel free to open a new issue in our [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. Why the high latency from Mumbai, Seoul, and São Paulo? Any known cause in details, please?